# Swap installations between Pis

Tags: pi-zero, opencv

I have RPi3 with OpenCV 3 installed on it. I have recently bought the Pi Zero and I noticed installing OpenCV 3 on the Zero would take 10 Hours!. Therefore, my question is whether I can replace the SD card from my PI3 to the Pi0 with all the OpenCV installations and OS? Will that work?

Or maybe someone knows a more efficient way to install OpenCV on the Pi0?

Thank you, Dan.

Answer (score 1):

In general images (at least Raspbian) are interchangeable between all models.

There are a few reservations - there are a few hardware differences, less memory, and it is possible to compile programs for ARM7 which will not run on ARM6.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I saw pre-compiled versions of OpenCV ready to be installed on RPi, is that a possible solution? here's a link -https://github.com/jabelone/OpenCV-for-Pi BTW, if compiling a version an a PC and then only transferring it to RPi is a solution, please explain how I can do this by my own.