# Switching SD card between Raspberry models

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

So I'm in the process of setting up OpenMediaVault and Plex on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, and an external HDD via a USB-hub.

Can I later just unplug the SD card and HDD, plug it all into a Raspberry 4 B, and expect everything to run normal? Or is there any procedure I need to do? Or is it just a bad idea.

Comment: in most cases you can use the same sd card with 32 bit Raspberry Pi OS in ANY model pi - not so much if you use something else - e.g. some rare images are created specifically for particular pi models, but since you tagged with raspberry pi os, there's likely no issue going between a 3B+ and 4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap installations between Pis](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78674/swap-installations-between-pis)

Comment: @Milliways, not really. because it's a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer seems to be that you can't switch from Raspberry Pi 3B+ to 4B. At least not with my specific installation.

I just got my new Pi 4 today, and booting up on various cards, USB flash drives and SSDs via USB, doesn't give me the LAN or WIFI.
Even going into raspi-config, I get an error, trying to set the country for my WIFI.

But the first error really shows up, during boot, where there's a counter for waiting for LAN to be connected. I'm sure, there is a really easy fix for this, like the Raspberry expect to have another IP or MAC adress, but since it's another unit, WIFI and LAN doesn't work.
But doing a ifconfig -a, reports the units correctly, showing each units's MAC adress. Just not an IP.